# GitHub GraphQL filter multi variable language filter

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm trying to use GitHub's GraphQL API to find a list of repos matching a query but limited to a specific language. However, I can't find anything in the docs relating to the multi variable language filter the typical online search supports or how something like this is typically done with GraphQL.

```graphql
{
  search(query: "language:java", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
          forkCount
          hasIssuesEnabled
          hasProjectsEnabled
          homepageUrl
          id
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I want to pass two params on language and show the result but this `query` just use string to search. I need to send a request as multi items like this
`language:['go','java','javaScript']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to build dynamic query with many `search` query targetting a specific language and [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) to avoid repetition of the `SearchResultItemConnection` in the query :

```graphql
{
  go: search(query: "language:go", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    ...SearchResult
  }
  java: search(query: "language:java", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    ...SearchResult
  }
  javascript: search(query: "language:javascript", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    ...SearchResult
  }
}

fragment SearchResult on SearchResultItemConnection {
  repositoryCount
  edges {
    node {
      ... on Repository {
        nameWithOwner
        forkCount
        hasIssuesEnabled
        hasProjectsEnabled
        homepageUrl
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20go%3A%20search%28query%3A%20%22language%3Ago%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2010%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...SearchResult%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20java%3A%20search%28query%3A%20%22language%3Ajava%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2010%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...SearchResult%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20javascript%3A%20search%28query%3A%20%22language%3Ajavascript%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2010%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...SearchResult%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20SearchResult%20on%20SearchResultItemConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20forkCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasIssuesEnabled%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasProjectsEnabled%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20homepageUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Note that it would only work for `OR` query (java or javascript or go for the list of languages) but not `AND`

The request can be built programmatically such as in this [python](/questions/tagged/python) script :

```python
import requests

token = "YOUR_TOKEN"
languages = ["go","java","javaScript"]

query = """
{
  %s
}

fragment SearchResult on SearchResultItemConnection {
  repositoryCount
  edges {
    node {
      ... on Repository {
        nameWithOwner
        forkCount
        hasIssuesEnabled
        hasProjectsEnabled
        homepageUrl
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

searchFragments = "".join([
    """
    %s: search(query: "language:%s", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
      ...SearchResult
    }
    """ % (t,t) for t in languages
])
r = requests.post("https://api.github.com/graphql",
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    },
    json = {
        "query": query % searchFragments
    }
)
print(r.json()["data"])
```